# Zabbix: delete no longer discoverable hosts

Tags: zabbix

I have a question about network discovery (via SNMP scanning for example) in Zabbix. The docs for that functionality are here: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/network_discovery/rule. It appears that once a host is discovered, entries are inserted into the `dhosts` and `dservices` tables. As a result, when one removes such a host using the web UI, the host re-reappears. It also appears that the solution for that is to manually remove the relevant entries from the two tables.

What's the rational behind reinserting the host despite my deleting it? Is the database deletion the only solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop discovering these hosts they must be switched off or have snmp disabled. (assuming you're only using snmp service as critera for discovery, it's also possible you have http services or other open ports that a host can be discovered on)

In your comment above you mentioned they've been dead for months? (Not used or switched off and disconnected?)

The discovery rule you configured will always run and always create a host whenever it discovers one unless you specify otherwise.

If you believe that you've already done this and zabbix is creating these hosts in error, can you bump up your logging level with

```
zabbix-server -R log_level_increase
```

Or by manually changing the

```
DebugLevel=
```

In /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf file -- i'd suggest changing this value to 4. If you edit the conf file then you will need to restart the zabbix-server service.

If you then manually execute the discovery rule and watch the zabbix-server log file with tailf. You should be able to see the results of the discovery scan.

Answer (score -1):

If you tell Zabbix to create an host each time the discovery runs and an host is available through SNMP, he better do exactly that, and quick.

If you do not want that host discovered, disable the discovery or change the host's SNMP configuration so that Zabbix can't discover it anymore.

Also, do not mess with the database: "*manually remove the relevant entries from the two tables*" is not a solution!

Comment: The hosts in question have been dead for months. They are re-inserted if I manually remove them from the web GUI. That's the issue.